# WCF Service 10s call for sync

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using Microsoft Sync Framework and am Synching every 10 seconds over a WCF service. On some system I have run into weird SemaphoreFullExceptions, so I'm trying to Refactor this Synching Background Thread.
Basically my question is: what approach to prefer:

```
private void SynchronizedWorker()
    {
        // Sync loop
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                SyncOrchestrator orchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
                SqlSyncProviderProxy destinationProvider = new SqlSyncProviderProxy("TEST");
                SqlSyncProvider localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("TEST", conn);
                // Set Providers
                orchestrator.LocalProvider = localProvider;
                orchestrator.RemoteProvider = destinationProvider;
                // Direction
                orchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;


                // Sync
                orchestrator.Synchronize();
            }


            // wait for next interval or being woken up
            if (_syncWaitEvent.WaitOne(10000))
            {
                // we have been signaled prior to the timeout expiring
                _syncForce = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

or this

```
SqlConnection conn;
    SyncOrchestrator orchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
    SqlSyncProviderProxy destinationProvider = new SqlSyncProviderProxy("TEST");
    SqlSyncProvider localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("TEST", conn);

    private void SynchronizedWorker2()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection();
        orchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
        destinationProvider = new SqlSyncProviderProxy("TEST");
        localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("TEST", conn);
        // Set Providers
        orchestrator.LocalProvider = localProvider;
        orchestrator.RemoteProvider = destinationProvider;
        // Direction
        orchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

        // Sync loop
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            // Sync
            orchestrator.Synchronize();

            // wait for next interval or being woken up
            if (_syncWaitEvent.WaitOne(10000))
            {
                // we have been signaled prior to the timeout expiring
                _syncForce = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Creating new objects for each sync for me seems to be the cleaner way to go. But of course it costs slightly more cpu time.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is use the same Orchestrator for sync, but In two cases I am disposing the objects (and recreating if needed):

- An error occured
- The application is being exited

Think this is the way to go...

Comment: I've never used "Sync", but if those objects implement IDisposable, then I strongly suggest keeping them in local variables and implementing `using` blocks.

Comment: The SyncOrchestrator does not implement IDisposable but the Providers do. But since I use a session to communicate with WCF I may keep the providers open as long as possible, because security negotiation can be cost intensive.